# Let $A,B,C$ be mutually independent events. Show that $B$ is independent from ($A \cap C$)'.

Tags: probability

Let $A,B,C$ be mutually independent events.  I want to show that $B$ is independent from ($A \cap C$)'.

**Thoughts:** I know this amounts to showing that
$P(B \cap (A \cap C)') = P(B)P((A \cap C)')$ and by tinkering with 
$B \cap (A \cap C)'$ I obtain

$B \cap (A \cap C)'=(B \cap A') \cup (B \cap C')$

I also know that $P(A \cap C') = P(A)P(C')$, but I am not sure how to connect all these ideas. Any hints on how to proceed appreciated.

Comment: Hints: B and A' are mutually independent. Ditto for B and C'. Apply these to the standard result that the probability of a union is the sum of the probabilities less the probability of their intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tip: $$(A\cap C)^\complement ~=~ A^\complement \cup C^\complement ~=~ \underbrace{(A^\complement\cap C)~\cup~ (A^\complement\cap C^\complement)~\cup~(A\cap C^\complement)}_{\text{a union of three disjoint intersctions}}$$

Also:

$$B\cap(A \cap C)^\complement ~=~ (A^\complement\cap B\cap C)~\cup~ (A^\complement\cap B\cap C^\complement)~\cup~(A\cap B\cap C^\complement)$$